# How do I use a char as the case in a switch-case?

Tags: java, switch-statement, character

How do I use a character in a switch-case? I will be getting the first letter of whatever the user inputs.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class SwitchCase {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String hello = "";
        hello = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input a letter: ");
        char hi = hello;
        switch(hi) {
            case 'a': System.out.println("a");
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
public class SwitCase {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hello = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input a letter: ");
        char hi = hello.charAt(0); // get the first char.
        switch(hi) {
            case 'a': System.out.println("a");
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 7):

[`charAt`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) gets a character from a string, and you can switch on them since `char` is an integer type.

So to switch on the first `char` in the `String` `hello`,

```
switch (hello.charAt(0)) {
  case 'a': ... break;
}
```

You should be aware though that Java `char`s do not correspond one-to-one with code-points.  See [`codePointAt`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#codePointAt%28int%29) for a way to reliably get a single Unicode codepoints.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double val1 = 100;
        double val2 = 10;
        char operation = 'd';
        double result = 0;

        switch (operation) {

            case 'a':
                result = val1 + val2; break;

            case 's':
                result = val1 - val2; break;
            case 'd':
                if (val2 != 0)
                    result = val1 / val2; break;
            case 'm':
                result = val1 * val2; break;

            default: System.out.println("Not a defined operation");


        }

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you are taking input from user:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
char alphabet = sc.next().charAt(0); //takes character input
switch(alphabet) {
    case 'a': System.out.println("a");
    break;
    case 'b': System.out.println("b");
    break;
    default: System.out.println("Error");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like that. Except `char hi=hello;` should be `char hi=hello.charAt(0)`. (Don't forget your `break;` statements).

Answer (score 0):

Using a char when the variable is a string won't work. Using

```
switch (hello.charAt(0))
```

you will extract the first character of the *hello* variable instead of trying to use the variable as it is, in string form. You also need to get rid of your space inside

```
case 'a '
```