# Entering character for switch statement selection

Tags: java, char, switch-statement

This question is regarding switch statement. These are a few similar posts on this (below) but I am still having trouble understanding.

[Using user-inputted characters in If/Switch statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676248/using-user-inputted-characters-in-if-switch-statements)

[How do I used a char as the case in a switch-case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906001/how-do-i-used-a-char-as-the-case-in-a-switch-case)

[Multiple characters in a switch statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611084/multiple-characters-in-a-switch-statement)

Please consider the following:

```
public class main
{
    public int selection; 

    public main()
    {
        System.out.println("MENU");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            showMenu();
            selection = in.nextInt();
            switch (selection)
            {
                case 1:
                    doSomething();
                break;              
                case 2:
                case 3: 

                default: 
                    System.out.println("Instruction is invalid");
            }
        } 
        while (selection !=7);
        { System.exit(0); }
}

public static void showMenu() 
    {
        System.out.print('\u000c');
        System.out.println("option 1 \n");
        System.out.println("option 2 \n");            
        System.out.println("7 - exit.\n");
        System.out.println("Select Option:\n");
    }
}
```

So this is a switch statement is for the user to choose options within the do while loop. The user enters an integer from the printed list to choose an option, after completion of the case, it loops back to menu.

My teacher informs me that its better practice to use char instead of int to get user input for the switch. I expect it to look something like this, but it doesn't work and I'm not sure why.

```
public class main
    {
    public int selection; 

    public main()
    {
        System.out.println("MENU");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            showMenu();
            String menu = "";
            char selection = menu.charAt();          
            switch (selection)
            {
                case 'A':
                doSomething();
                break;                
                case 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
                default: 
                System.out.println("Instruction is invalid");
            }
        } 
        while (selection != 'QQ');
        { System.exit(0); }
}
```

In the second link posted there was an answer which i think suggested using 
      hello.charAt(0)
as the switch condition?

```
  switch (hello.charAt(0)) 
      {
          case 'a': ... break;
      }
```

I have three specific questions on this code:

1) My code doesn't work. Should my condition be hello.charAt(0) ?

2) I would like to use QQ as the quit option on the switch. Is possible with the code above? From the second link, I think it should be fine.

3) It is also shown here ([switch statement using char in the case condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809355/switch-statement-using-char-in-the-case-condition)) that the case statement should have double quotations. Could someone please clarify this as well?

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: where is the main method : `public static void main(String[] args)` ?

Comment: `while (selection != 'QQ')` This won't work because anything within single quotes is a character literal. QQ is not a single character - it's a string.

Comment: "*My code doesn't work.*" - What does not work? Please be precise. Define the input, as well as the expected and observed behaviour. "*I would like to use QQ...*"- What do you mean by "QQ"? The String `"QQ"`? If so: no, you would have to read and switch `String`s, not `char`s. "*[...] that the case statement should have double quotations.*" - I recommend a basic Java tutorial. `"`-quoted texts are `String`s, while `'`-quote single characters are `char`s.

Comment: Thank you @Turing85 for the info. I read up a little on the quotation stuff. I had not previously picked up on that. Much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you @Michael.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work better:

```
do {
    showMenu();
    String menu = in.nextLine(); // read a line of input
    char selection;
    if (menu.length>0) selection = menu.charAt(0); // extract the first char of the line read
    else selection = '\0'; // special char when input is empty...

    switch (selection) {
    case 'A': case 'a':
         doSomething();
         break;
    case 'Q': case 'q':
         break;
    default: 
         System.out.println("Instruction is invalid");
    }
} while (selection != 'Q' && selection != 'q');
```

`menu` stores the full input line. `selection` would be the first char (if it exists) of the line.

Comment: minor optimization: `if (menu.length>0) selection = menu.toLowerCase().charAt(0);` - this gets rid of the upper-case cases.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. Both are excellent. I now see that the statement works pretty much the same way as for integers. That lowercase/uppercase code is really nice.

Comment: @Turing85 Right, but I let it that way because OP may want to distinguish the cases.

Answer (score 0):

To use .charAt() you need to supply the index - so if you want to use the first character then use 0, etc.

Comment: @Turing85 I am pretty sure he references the line `menu.charAt()` with `String menu = ""`.

Answer (score 0):

In general one read an entire line instead of a single keystroke:

The first char of a String is gotten by `charAt(0)`. However the string
could have length 0. There is the if-expression `CONDITION ? TRUEVALUE : FALSEVALUE`.

```
    String menu = in.readLine();
    char selection = menu.isEmpty() ? ' ' : menu.charAt(0);
    switch (selection) {
        case 'A':
            doSomething();
            break;
        case '2':
        case '3':
        case '4':
            ...
            break;
        default: 
            System.out.println("Instruction is invalid");
    }
```

There is an even more succint solution:

```
    String menuSelection = in.readLine();
    switch (menuSelection) {
        case "A":
            doSomething();
            break;
        case "2":
        case "3":
        case "4":
            ...
            break;
        default: 
            System.out.println("Instruction is invalid");
    }
```

Comment: I like the use of the ternary operator there. Can i use like this though? `char selection = menu.isEmpty() ? (System.out.println("invalid input"+selection)) : menu.charAt(0);`

Comment: Actually, comment is incorrect. As you said, the first part of ? is if the condition is true, the second part is if the condition is false. Switching my code around, would something like that work? In the case of the user entering nothing I'd want to notify the user.

Comment: Leave it for expressions, though it indeed is an if-then-else, with a result, the type of which is the common one between then-part and else-part.